# MySql is logging my Update query, but doesn't actually perform the update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am updating an object through Hibernate, but despite the SQL appearing in the MySql logs with no errors, the update doesn't seem to occur.

I'm executing my request through Hibernate. I have traced the code through [this line in the mysql-connector code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/5.1.41/src/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java#L1756), and everything looks good.

When this line is executed, an update query that looks correct appears in my sql log (it's identical to what the `PreparedStatement` contained). If I copy this SQL query straight from the log and execute it in a different connection, it works and the data is updated correctly. However, without running it manually, MySql logs the query, but the data is not updated.

We don't have any triggers on the table we are performing the update on, nor on its schema.

**Versions:** Hibernate 3.6.10, MySql Connector J 5.1.41, Mysql 5.6

**Side Note:**

It's worth noting that Hibernate seems to believe the object has been updated, even after an eviction. I tested this by opening an eval console in Idea and executing a `findById`.

Hibernate returned the updated object, but MySql didn't log anything, indicating I probably had to `evict` the object from Hibernate. I evicted the object (also through the eval popup) and performed another `findById`. This time a `select` query is written in the MySql logs and *the updated object is returned*.

However, copying the `select` query from the sql logs and executing it in another connection directly against the DB does NOT return the updated object -- it returns the old object. Weird.

Comment: show the code(tm)?

Comment: "show the code(tm)?" you mean code ™ (alt + 0153)  right ? @danblack

Comment: Is the update being executed in a transaction that is never committed?

Comment: "I evicted the object (also through the **eval** popup)" Topicstarter if `eval()` is the answer then you are asking yourself the wrong question..

Comment: @Raymon Nijland I was referring to the `evaluate expression` debug tool in intellij: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html. @danblack sorry, wasn't sure what to show. `this.save(object)`? After that it was all hibernate and mysql connector. But if that `@Transactional` annotation had been lower in the callstack we might have found it ;)

Comment: ok forget mine comment about `eval()` then now i notice the tag `java` which does not have a `eval()` function geuss i need coffee.. never mind java seams also to have a [eval()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn you transactions! (It's the machines fault, not mine, right?)

I didn't realize it, but my updates were being rolled into a transaction. This was happening in a method pretty far up the call-chain. The transaction ended up never being committed because of an exception, also thrown further down the line. I'm not super familiar with transactions, and hadn't thought of this as a potential cause. A coworker found the issue by stepping back and noticing the Spring annotation. This can also be noticed in the MySql logs, I just missed it.

Thanks for those that looked and commented!

Comment: I have to wait 2 days